# convert Unsigned Int to array of chars (String)

Tags: microchip, xc8

### EDIT: I am using this for programming a pic, so the C will be quite limited. The compiler is XC8.

Following function expects me to pass a string:

```
void OLED_string(char* str, short x, short y) {

    short pos = 0;
    char character = str[pos++];
    short startx = x;
    short starty = y;
    while(character != '\0') {
        OLED_char(character, startx, starty);
        if(startx >= 123) starty++; //wrap around
        startx += 5;
        character = str[pos++];
    }
}
```

I would like to display a value I have in a unsigned Integer. This value should be converted to Float and then divided by ten. Since float is very slow I would prefer to convert the integer to a string, and then simply add a point before the last character. I tried to pass directly the integer to this function but it does not work.
Thanks!

Comment: This is straight c. It would fit better in stack overflow.

Comment: Well, its the code for a microcontroller programmed with mplab and xc8 compiler. People in this forum have a better specific knowledge as this c is quite limited if compared to the full C that the guys over there are used to..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use C standard library functions, sprintf() should handle the string conversion. Instead of adding the decimal point by shuffling characters around, you could use integer arithmetic:

```
char str[20];
unsigned int value = 105;

sprintf(str, "%u.%u", value / 10, value % 10);
```

Integer division won't be fast, but it should be faster than floating point. And I suspect that the int -> string conversion algorithm will be doing division anyway.

Comment: snprintf version is better as it limits buffer usage.

Comment: Thanks! Will this work in mplab with xc8 compilrr?

Comment: It should. This is ANSI-standard C.

Comment: The % gave me this error in MPLAB X, `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')`

Comment: @R1S8K C's modulus division operator (%) only works on integers. If you need to use doubles, you can use the fmod() function from math.h, or (if your platform supports it) pass the double to sprintf using the %f format specifier.

Comment: @AdamHaun Thanks man for the information, I stopped using `sprintf`, it eats all the flash memory, maybe because it's an old 8-bit microcontroller. I used `itoa` and it works well except it only accept `int` I just have to extract the decimal point of the float number coming from LM35 input.

Comment: @R1S8K That works. Standard library *printf() functions tend to be pretty bloated. You can find smaller versions online, e.g. here: https://github.com/mpaland/printf

Comment: @AdamHaun Will this library work on `MPLAB X IDE` ?

Comment: It's standard C, so it should. If you just want sprintf() I don't think you have to do any of the printf() implementation stuff in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The `itoa` function is your friend. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: Thanks, but im not sure that this is supported by the xc8 compiler..

Comment: can you just try it out?

Comment: Yep, it worked with me on MPLAB X IDE using `PIC16F877A`.

Answer (score 1):

`itoa` and `ftoa` functions are both in `stdlib.h` in XC8 compiler so they will work on PIC. Just include `<stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 0):

**ITOA bei XC8:**

```
int main(void) {
  char Buffer[7];
  int i = 12345;
  itoa(Buffer, i, 10);
  UART_Write_Text_NL((uChr)Buffer); 
  return;
}
```